# Drawing curved text counter clock wise instead clock wise

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I'd like to draw curved text counter clock wise. So far I've only made it to the curving.

```
public class TextDrawActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   

    setContentView(new TextDrawingView(this));
  }   

  static class TextDrawingView extends View {
    private Path arc;
    private RectF bounds;
    private TextPaint textPaint;    

    public TextDrawingView(Context context) {
      super(context);   

      arc = new Path();
      bounds = new RectF();
      textPaint = new TextPaint();
      textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      textPaint.setTextSize(50);
      textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }   

    @Override public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
      super.draw(canvas);   

      bounds.set(0f, 0f, getWidth() * 0.8f, getHeight() / 2.f);   

      arc.rewind(); // Clear internal structure.
      arc.addArc(bounds, 45, 360);
      canvas.drawTextOnPath("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.",
          arc, 0, textPaint.getTextSize() / 2.f, textPaint);
    }
  }
}
```

With this code, it'll look like this:

[image: Text]

How can I draw the text counter clock wise so it won't be upside down anymore?

Comment: Have you triend to initialize `Path` [counter-clockwise](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.Direction.html)?

Comment: @azizbekian there's no overload for addArc with the Direction

Comment: I think [this](https://hemantvc.blogspot.de/2016/10/text-curve-clockwise-and-anticlockwise_95.html) will help you.

Comment: use negative `sweepAngle` in `addArc`

Comment: @pskink thanks that was easy. Mind posting it as an answer so I can approve it?

Comment: feel free to make a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) answered in the comments, a negative `sweepAngle` can be used to achieve this effect:

```
@Override public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
  super.draw(canvas);

  bounds.set(0f, 0f, getWidth() * 0.8f, getHeight() / 2.f);

  arc.rewind(); // Clear internal structure.
  arc.addArc(bounds, 135, -180);
  canvas.drawTextOnPath("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.", arc, 0, textPaint.getTextSize() / 2.f, textPaint);
}
```

Comment: note that you are calling `arc.addArc` inside `draw` method so it will add and add and add... you know what i mean?

Comment: Yup it's just for brewity. In my real code I'm only doing it once or I'm using `arc.rewind()`. I'll update it though.